# How to delete a pod from Kubernetes master node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Does anyone know how to delete pod from kubernetes master node? I have this one master node on bare-metal ubuntu server. When i'm trying to delete it with "kubectl delete pod .." or force deleting from there: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/ it doesnt work. the pod is creating again and again...

Comment: you should scale down the deploiment to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pods in a Statefulsets are managed by ReplicaSets and will be recreated again if the current and the desired replicas defined in the spec do not match.

The document you linked provides instructions as to how to kill the pods forcefully avoiding the graceful shutdown behaviour which can have unexpected behaviour depending on the application.

The link clearly states the pods will be recreated in the section:

> Force deletions do not wait for confirmation from the kubelet that the Pod has been terminated. Irrespective of whether a force deletion is successful in killing a Pod, it will immediately free up the name from the apiserver. This would let the StatefulSet controller create a replacement Pod with that same identity; this can lead to the duplication of a still-running Pod, and if said Pod can still communicate with the other members of the StatefulSet, will violate the at most one semantics that StatefulSet is designed to guarantee.

If you want the pods to be stopped and new pods for the Statefulset do not get created, you need to scale down the Statefulset by changing the replicas to 0.

You can read the official docs for [how to scale the Statefulset replicas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/scale-stateful-set/).

Comment: Hi! :) Thank you, i did it, i changed the replicas to 0 and it did work

Comment: Glad to be of help, @Skyeee :)

Answer (score 0):

The key to figuring out how to kill the pod will be to understand how it was created. For example, if the pod is part of a deployment with a declared replicas count as 1,  Once you kill/ force kill, Kubernetes detects a mismatch between the desired state (the number of replicas defined in the deployment configuration) to the current state and will create a new pod to replace the one that was deleted - therefor in this example you will need to either scale the deployment to 0 or delete the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to kill any pod we can just scale down the replica set.

```
kubectl scale deploy <deployment_name> --replicas=<expected_no_of_replicas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Way of deleting pods will depends on how you created it. If you created it individually ( not part of a `ReplicaSet/ReplicationController/Deployment` ) then you can delete pod directly. otherwise the only option to delete is the `scale` option. In production setup what I believe is all are using `Deployment` option out of `ReplicaSet/ReplicationController/Deployment`( Please refer documents and understand  the difference between all those three options )